# Returning promise from function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I am using the Parse Baas library. I have some functions defined that call various Parse Cloud code functions. I currently have a basic understanding of javascript promises. One thing I am struggling with is how to handle the following

I have a custom function which I can call from other modules.

```
   function CustomFunction()
   {
        var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
        var gameScore = new GameScore();
        gameScore.set("score", 1337);
        gamesScore.save().then(
          function(object) {
              // the object was saved.
              // What do I return from here??
        },
        function(error) {
                // saving the object failed.
                 // What do I return from here??
         });
   }
```

There are some cases where I would maybe want to fail inside gamesScore.save().then( function(object) {} so I don't want to do just return gamescore.save().
Now when i call the custom function it really needs to return a promise as the code contained within it is 'asynchronous'. So what do i return from inside the custom function.

```
   CustomFunction().then(
      function(result) {

    },
    function(error) {

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `gamesScore.save()` is already a promise, you can simply return it from `CustomFunction`

```
function CustomFunction() {
  ...
  return gamesScore.save();
}
```

Now you should be able to use `CustomFunction` like so

```
CustomFunction().then(function(data) {
  ...
}, function(err) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I have some cases where I would like to fail in gamesScore.save().then(},   so I don't want to do this return gamesScore.save();

Comment: That's a thing with returning promise from `CustomFunction`. Either you return the promise, or you fulfill the promise (resolve/reject) and return the value. You can't have both scenarios in play. If you want to return a promise, then handle the error in the caller. If you want to handle the error within `CustomFunction`, it would be better to handle the promise there only.

Comment: Thanks, so  how do I handle the promise inside CustomFunction

Comment: Define 2 callbacks and pass them to `CustomFunction`. `SuccessCallback(object) { ... }` and `ErrorCallback(error) { ... }` and then pass them to the `.then()`, eg. `.then(SuccessCallback, ErrorCallback)`. You handle the values within these callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Then .then() callback in your CustomFunction serves as a filter. If you want to alter the resolved/rejected results first, you can do that there. Otherwise, don't use .then(). Just return the .save() function

```
function CustomFunction()
{
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
    var gameScore = new GameScore();
    gameScore.set("score", 1337);
    return gamesScore.save();
}
```

Afterwards, use the result using .done(result) or .fail(error)

```
CustomFunction().done(function(result){ console.log(result); });
```